# Trying to extract the source link of the first image of a google search using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to have a program that returns the image link for the first image of a google search.

The link I am trying to get is if you were click the first image, right clicking the image that appears and then opening the image.  The current code I have is.

```
r = requests.get(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
link = soup.find('img', class_='irc_mi')['src']
return link
```

However I get a type error that says "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: could you give us an example of a page you wish to get the image from? Just a typical gooogle image search?

Comment: If you were to search up python using the program it would give you this [link](https://www.python.org/static/opengraph-icon-200x200.png).  This link is gotten from searching python on google images, clicking the first result, and then right clicking and opening the image in a new tab.

Comment: I dont think the links for those are on the page when its loaded. i.e. if you're trying to get the 'large version', you'd have to actually let the page load, click on it, and then pull the source. This is still possible, using something like selenium.

Comment: Display some block of example which you want to retrieve the content from it. so that you can receive answer you are searching for

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `src` attributes are added due to the JavaScript running in the browser. You can use [`Requests-HTML`](https://html.python-requests.org/) to achieve your goal:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.google.pl/search?q=python&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif6Zq7i8vaAhVMLVAKHUDkDa4Q_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=681'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()

first_image = r.html.find('.rg_ic.rg_i', first=True)
link = first_image.attrs['src']
```

Comment: Does that download every link from the webpage?  As after running it, it seems to be downloading something.  If it is downloading all the links that seems like it would take a long time for the users image search to process.

Comment: [RequestsHTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) has a [JavaScript support](https://html.python-requests.org/#javascript-support) that uses Chromium behind the scenes. I believe that's the reason why it takes a while for the script to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `selenium` but the execution time will be slower than using `bs4`.

To scrape the original image link using  `bs4`, you need to parse `<script>` tags with `regex` and then parse those links.

For example, part of the code (*check out [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Images-with-Python#bs4_original_images.py)*):

```py
# find all script tags
all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

# find all full res images
matched_google_full_resolution_images = re.findall(r"(?:'|,),\[\"(https:|http.*?)\",\d+,\d+\]",
                                                    all_script_tags)

# iterate over found matches and decode them
for fixed_full_res_image in matched_google_full_resolution_images:
    original_size_img_not_fixed = bytes(fixed_full_res_image, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    original_size_img = bytes(original_size_img_not_fixed, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    print(original_size_img)

-----
'''
https://external-preview.redd.it/mAQWN2kUYgFS3fgm6LfYo37AY7i2e_YY8d83_1jTeys.jpg?auto=webp&s=b2bad0e23cbd83426b06e6a547ef32ebbc08e2d2
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_mR0JBLXRLY/maxresdefault.jpg
https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/37454.jpg
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this easily by using [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't need to figure out how to scrape something or maintain the parser if something will change over time. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and extract needed data.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os, json
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "minecraft shaders 8k photo",
  "tbm": "isch"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(json.dumps(results['suggested_searches'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
print(json.dumps(results['images_results'], indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

------
'''
[
...
  {
    "position": 30,
    "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_CjA8J1P5Y6bN2KCuY6XgS4mFvctuwhho6A&usqp=CAU",
    "source": "wallpaperbetter.com",
    "title": "minecraft shaders video games, HD wallpaper | Wallpaperbetter",
    "link": "https://www.wallpaperbetter.com/en/hd-wallpaper-cusnk",
    "original": "https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/120/342/446/minecraft-shaders-video-games-wallpaper-preview.jpg",
    "is_product": false
  }
...
]
'''
```

I have already answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68878748/15164646) and wrote a dedicated blog about how [scrape and download Google Images with Python](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-images-with-python-1ee2).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo - `_class` not `class`.

Also - you don't actually need to supply the class name attribute.

```
r = requests.get(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
link = soup.find("img", "irc_mi")["src"]
return link
```

Comment: Even after removing the class_ , i still receive the same error