# Scraping Script tag in HTML with Json and BS4

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to be able to scrape the code from the webpage for this link https://secure.ewaypayments.com/sharedpage/sharedpayment?AccessCode=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==

I am currently using json and bs4 with python.

full page source
https://pastebin.com/iU5c9GBF

```
<div class="Actions">
                <input class="action" type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Place Order" title="Place Order" onclick="return showModal()" disabled="disabled" />
              <input type="hidden" id="EWAY_TransactionID" name="EWAY_TransactionID" value="" />
              <script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"> </script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                var eWAYConfig = {
                  sharedPaymentUrl: "https://secure.ewaypayments.com/sharedpage/sharedpayment?AccessCode=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
                };
                function showModal()
                {
                  // verify captcha

                  // show modal
                  return eCrypt.showModalPayment(eWAYConfig, resultCallback);
                }
                function resultCallback(result, transactionID, errors) {
                  if (result == "Complete") {
                    document.getElementById("EWAY_TransactionID").value = transactionID;
                    document.getElementById("Form_PaymentForm").submit();
                    //Please wait until we process your order, James at 9/10/2017
                    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
                  }
                  else if (errors != "")
                  {
                    alert("There was a problem completing the payment: " + errors);
                  }
                }
              </script>
```

Previously Used Code

```
s = requests.session()
orderurl = s.get('https://www.supplystore.com.au/shop/checkout/submit.aspx')
soup = bs(orderurl.text, 'html.parser')
find = soup.find("div", {"class": "Actions"}).find("script")[1]
```

Comment: Maybe you mean't  `.find_all("script")[1]` ?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are after from that script tag

Answer (score 1):

You cannot utilize BeautifulSoup for parsing Javascript data, but you can use `re` module (`data` is your HTML code):

```
import re    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')    
txt = soup.select('.Actions script')[1].text

print(re.search(r'sharedPaymentUrl:\s*"(.*?)"', txt)[1])
```

Prints:

```
https://secure.ewaypayments.com/sharedpage/sharedpayment?AccessCode=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
```

Comment: You need to post some data to the site (e.g. using `requests.post()`). Just getting the page `https://www.supplystore.com.au/shop/checkout/submit.aspx` doesn't contain your data.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using bs4 4.7.1. :contains and split

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 #html would be response text  e.g. r = requests.get(url): soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

html = '''

<div class="Actions">
                <input class="action" type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Place Order" title="Place Order" onclick="return showModal()" disabled="disabled" />
              <input type="hidden" id="EWAY_TransactionID" name="EWAY_TransactionID" value="" />
              <script src="https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js"> </script>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                var eWAYConfig = {
                  sharedPaymentUrl: "https://secure.ewaypayments.com/sharedpage/sharedpayment?AccessCode=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
                };
                function showModal()
                {
                  // verify captcha

                  // show modal
                  return eCrypt.showModalPayment(eWAYConfig, resultCallback);
                }
                function resultCallback(result, transactionID, errors) {
                  if (result == "Complete") {
                    document.getElementById("EWAY_TransactionID").value = transactionID;
                    document.getElementById("Form_PaymentForm").submit();
                    //Please wait until we process your order, James at 9/10/2017
                    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
                  }
                  else if (errors != "")
                  {
                    alert("There was a problem completing the payment: " + errors);
                  }
                }
              </script>

'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml') 
target = 'sharedPaymentUrl: '
script = soup.select_one('.Actions script:contains("' + target + '")')
if script is None:
    url = 'N/A'
else:
    url = script.text.split(target)[1].split('\n')[0]
print(url)
```